# Is there an alternative for tabular?

Tags: tables, design

I have an amount of objects (*can be any amount - 1, 5, 10...*)

They have about 12 characteristics - maybe **+/-** several, but not less than 9 I believe.

The question is, is there any more appropriate form of presentation of those objects all together than the table form? does it make any sense to play with the presentation - or the table is perfect?

Charts and diagrams are not applicable, the data is not about analytics, it is about to display and view all the objects. So no graphical.

Comment: Feed us some more info. It's not enough to help. What are these objects and what's their purpose? Also what you have thought of? and any reference would be even better.

Answer (score 1):

A table is just fine, but there's an awful lot you can do with a table!

Just because information is in a table doesn't stop you making it easy to scan, see connected information, identify groups, emphasize important items, and generally ensure that the data itself is in the foreground and the 'table decoration' itself fade into the background.

The decision to use a table is easy. Deciding how to *present* the information in the table is the hard part and it depends entirely on the information you have.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on the 12 characteristics of your objects. Do they have a chorological sequence? You could use a **timeline** view. Do you have dependent data? May be the **tree** structure would suit. Or it could be **cards** or **expandable lists** etc.

More importantly, what is the primary use-case for your users? What's their intent?